# Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: cboMotivo

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find an element on the page by ID, but even though the element has an ID, selenium displays the message that the element could not be found.

I created a class called InvalidLogin that extends the BaseClass class. In the InvalidLogin class, there is a method called fillTreatmentOps. In this method I try to find the element by ID (cboMotivo), but I can not. Below is the class code and screen prints.

```
public class BaseClass {

WebDriver driver;
@BeforeClass
public void setupApplication() {
    Reporter.log("Instanciando o navegador", true);

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "e:\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://10.5.9.45/BkoMais_Selenium/");

    Reporter.log("Aplicação inicializada", true);
}
    @AfterClass
    public  void closeApplication() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            //driver.quit();
            Reporter.log("Sessão do navegador finalizada",true);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }       
}

public class InvalidLogin extends BaseClass {

@Test(description = "Logando na aplicação")
public void logarBkoMais() {
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.id("matricula_I")).sendKeys("844502");
        driver.findElement(By.id("senha_I")).sendKeys("Bcc201707");
        driver.findElement(By.id("bt_entrar")).click();
        // driver.navigate().back();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Test(description = "Acessando a estratégia BackOffice >> NET >> Facilidades")
public void logarEstrategiaNetFacilidades() {

    driver.findElement(By.id("mn_backoffice")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("mn_bkoffice_prod_217")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("mn_bkoffice_est_179")).click();

}

@Test(description = "Registro >> Novo")
public void registroNovo() {
    driver.findElement(By.id("mn_registro")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("mn_novo_caso")).click();
}
@Test(description = "Facilidades >> Tratamento Os")
public void preencherCamposTratamentoOs() {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    WebElement analiseC = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("cboMotivo")));
    driver.findElement(By.id("cboMotivo")).click(); 
}
```

}

[cboMotivo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNTl9.jpg)
[Element ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eonzn.jpg)
[Console Eclipse Erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgX1Z.jpg)

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Based on the error message, it simply cannot locate the element.  What framework are you using?  TestNG?  Perhaps the tests are not running in the order that you think they are, and when the test in question is being run, the element does not (yet) exist on the web page?

Comment: Bill Hileman, I'm using TESTNG. I did a test using JUnit and selenium was able to find the element. I do not know why using the TESTNG the same element is not found.
Do you have any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: I solved the problem by numbering the methods. For example: logarBkoMais1, logarEstrategiaNetFacilidades2,registroNovo3 and tratamentoFacilidades4. After Bill Hileman's hint that maybe the excution sequence was not right, I decided to number the methods and it worked. Thanks you all!

Answer (score 0):

This problem hit me, it's very rare because i found that adding time.sleep(2) allows Selenium firefox driver to find the element, i can't find what's is going on under the hood.

```
time.sleep(2)
            try:
                action_button = WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT).until(
                    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_btn"))
                )
                action_button.click()
```

it doesn't work without explicit sleep(2)

Comment: The problem was that bootstrap asynchronous dynamic styling had a delay and selenium got lost in an endless loop